# "Unexpected Token" on AutoSave

Tags: reactjs, webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

I get an error "Unexpected Token" in the following local environment: "React, Webpack, Webpack-Dev-Server, Babel, Material-UI".

[image]

Specificities: I use Auto-Save in VS-Code. In the Error-Log I can recognize that the error occurs in the middle of my code-edit. For example, before I finish a method. Even if I finish the code-edit, the update is not being updated in the browser. 
When I restart the dev-server, everything works normally until the same error eventually occurs again.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a scenario ,some code ,for which you are getting the error ? Since , what this error generally means is that the code didn't expect something to be at the place where it is,.

Comment: @Ankush Verma: 
Thanks for taking time.
Usually it happens when working on MaterialUI-Components, for example:
" <Typography style={{backgroundColor: "red }}>"

But it should not be the problem, because when I restart the dev-server, everything works again normal for a certain period of time.

Comment: for a certain period of time or until you open a specific component? because if it works ,it shouldn't break if nothing is changing.

Comment: @Ankush Verma: 
It's not for a specific period of time nor for a specific component. 
It's more like: If the error occurs, the browser stops to take any updates from the vs-code and thus the error stay in the console.

Comment: Do you see any error on the Vscode terminal ?

Comment: @Ankush Verma:
I allways get this error-message as well: 
"[WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented."
This might bring me closer to the solution

Comment: I opened a fresh question, that better describes the bug:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998009/webpack-dev-server-errors-while-compiling-reload-prevented-stack-react